# Navbar bootstrap 3 not working in mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap to make a blog. Put a navbar that is functioning properly on the desktop, when it gets to a smaller screen size, scroll the navbar.

When trying to do the same process on a mobile, scroll the navbar does not work.

Below the image as it is.

The blog url: www.sesmt.org
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZbcW.png

Code in Jsfiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/mtsys/Qs4zw/

```
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="sidebar-nav">
      <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inner" role="navigation">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".sidebar-navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <span class="visible-sm visible-xs navbar-brand">Menu Clique para abrir</span>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse sidebar-navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="dados">Principal</li>
            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Home/Contato">Contato</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Últimas Atualizações</a></li>
            <li><a href="/">Mapa do Site</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Blog/Categoria/41">Precisa de ajuda?</a></li>
            <li class="dados">Geral</li>
            <li><a href="/Blog/Categoria/40">Diversos</a></li>            
            <li><a href="#">Processos</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Notícias</a></li>            
            <li class="dados">SESMT</li>
            <li><a href="/Blog/Secao/6">Normas</a></li>
            <li><a href="/ConsultaCA">Consulta CA</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Consulta CNAE, CID-10, CBO</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Categoria/10">Implantação</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Categoria/12">PPP</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">PPRA</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">PCMSO</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">A.P.R.</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Cartilhas</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Check-List</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">DDS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">DDS - Lista</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">EPI</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Mapa de Riscos</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ordens de Serviços (OS)</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Placas</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Procedimentos</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Diversos</a></li>            
            <li><a href="#">Perguntas / Respostas</a></li>            
            <li class="dados">Multimidia <span class="badge text-right">52</span></li>
            <li><a href="#">Fotos</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Vídeos</a></li>
            <li class="dados">Emprego</li>
            <li><a href="#">Vagas</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you should add css to nav controller

```
overflow-y: auto !important;
```